# I'm trying to write a Python program to find the number of notes in an integer, but my code isn't working

Tags: python

Look at this image for easier understanding

[image]

This is what the python program should do. The notes to use are [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10]

Can someone explain what is wrong with my code? I've been sitting here and scratching my head for the longest time.

```
def note_calculator(num):
    notes = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10]
    counter = 0
    mult = 0
    for x in range(6):
        enote = notes[x]
        if num <= enote:
            if num % enote == 0:
                mult = num / enote
                num = num - (mult * enote)
                counter += mult
                if num == 0:
                    break
            else:
                num = num - enote
                counter += 1
                if num == 0:
                    break
        else:
            continue
    return counter
```

Basically, my method is to put sample notes in a list and iterate through all of them. If the number you input is greater or equal to the first iteration (500) it will then check the divisibility, if there are no remainders, I calculate the multiple. Then I subtract the multiple * the sample note iteration (500) because the program should run until the input (num) is equal to zero. Then I add to the counter, which will tell me the number of notes. If it is not divisible with remainders I simply subtract the first iteration (500) and add it to the counter. This repeats until the last iteration (10)

I know there is an easier and shorter way to do this, but whatever.

Comment: FYI: You don't need `else: continue`. Loops automatically continue unless you break out of them.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: Why `if note <= enote`? Did you mean `if note >= enote`?

Comment: Do you have an example input where it is not returning correctly?

Comment: I think you meant to write `if num >= enote` instead of `if num <= enote`

Comment: The `else:` block only subtracts one of the current note. You need to subtract as many of them as will multiply to less than the value of `num`.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm works fine, but I noticed two bugs, first one:

`if num <= enote:` should be `if num >= enote:`
You want to get enote when it's not bigger than rest amount, not otherwise.

Second, notice that when `if num % enote == 0:` you correctly take proper amount of enotes, but in `else` clause you take only one. You should take as much as you can, so do something similar as in `if`:

```
counter += num // enote
num = num % enote
```

And one small thing, your function now returns float (as / operator do so). You can use //, look:

```
print(type(10/2)) # <class 'float'>
print(type(10//2)) # <class 'int'>
```

Comment: The algorithm isn't correct if it needs to use more than one of a note.

Comment: I run it for 880 and 1000 and worked for both cases.

Comment: Indeed, I read it more carefully, updating answer

Comment: Try it with 1010.

Comment: I need to get rid of the modulus thing because it works for numbers like 1000, 500, 1500 but not with numbers like 1010 because 1010 % 500 is not 0... so the whole thing messes up. it works with 880 because there is no modulus needed. at least that's what I think. @Barmar, what do you mean it isn't correct if it needs to use more than one note?

Comment: It's perfectly fine 1010 % 500 is not zero. It's meaning is - let's take as much 500 as I can (`it's 1010 // 500 == 2`) and what's left? Ofc `1010 % 500 == 10`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are looking for the builtin `divmod`.

```
notes = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10]
x = 880
s = 0
for n in notes: 
    q,r = divmod(x,n)
    x   = r
    s  += q
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would implement it (Python 3):

```
def note_calculator(num):
    counter = 0
    for note in [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10]:
        counter += num // note
        num %= note
    return counter
```

In Python 2, you can just replace the `//` with a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it like this...

```py
from time import time

start = time()

def note_calculator(num):
    notes, count= [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10], 0

    for note in notes:
        if note <= num:
            multiplier = num // note
            num -= note*multiplier
            count += multiplier
    return count

print(note_calculator(880))
print(note_calculator(1000))

end = time()

print(f"Time Taken : {end-start}")
```

Output:-

```
6
2
Time Taken : 3.695487976074219e-05
```